# Search engine (elastic search + meteor): Is javascript array manipulation inefficient for arrays containing up to thousands of results?

Tags: javascript, meteor, elasticsearch, full-text-search, search-engine

I am working on a project in Meteor which uses ElasticSearch as a search engine. I need the search feature on the site to allow 'stacking' searches. So, for instance, one can search for a file that a user in a certain 'group' uploaded by 'stacking' the user's name, followed by the group name and ending with the file name or some content in the file.

Now, on the MongoDB database the group, user, and files would be stored in separate collections and be related to each other through Ids. However, ElasticSearch uses a distributed datastore where everything is 'flat'. This makes it necessary to denormalize data/do application-side joins/etc. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html).

**My question is**: which method would be the best...

1. Denormalize data, use nests, etc.

   --> So, when rivering data to the elasticsearch datastore, I would make copies of the data and replace every parent element with a new one which has the data added to it.
   FOR EX. If someone comments on let's say a post in a group. The server would have to add to the general list of comments + find the post object, append the comment to it, and re-add the post object to the database + update the group object which contains the post object which should contain the comment + do the same for a user object (since I want to be able to stack searches on groups, users, etc.).
   **Basically** When ever something is added or deleted, I'd have to update every object in the database that relates to it.
2. Run multiple elastic search queries (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/application-joins.html) to retrieve the data I want.
3. Just perform search queries on each de-centralized collection, and use javascript on the server-side to compare the arrays and produce the search results.

** Note: this is for scaling up to a relatively mid-level load/usage. So around hundreds-thousands of instances of data to search through. Although, if this can work larger scale (millions), that would be great!

Please correct me if my understanding of anything is wrong, and thank you for reading through all this!